# The Density Matrix of a Pure State

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, density-operator, normalization

It is my understanding that any pure quantum state $|\psi\rangle$ can be represented by the density matrix $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$.

It is also my understanding that $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ represents a transformation that projects any vector onto the ray of $|\psi\rangle$, and thus  $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ can be identified with the ray of $|\psi\rangle$ itself.

First Question: Is it correct that $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ can be identified with the ray of $|\psi\rangle$?

Second Question: If the answer to the first question is positive, then how is it that  $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ can represent the pure state  $|\psi\rangle$? I mean, the ray of a vector does not contain information about the magnitude (length) of the vector.
Is it simply that we assume that quantum states are normalized and the magnitude of $|\psi\rangle$ is 1 in any case?

Comment: 1. I do not understand what you mean by "identifying" here. The projector onto a subspace and the subspace itself are different mathematical objects. 2. I don't understand what you're going for in the second question at all - every vector in a given "ray" represents the same quantum state, the "length" is entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure states are defined as rays of vectors, although different books choose to give different sorts of emphasis on this. Notice that if $\vert\psi\rangle = \alpha \vert\phi\rangle$ for any *constant* $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, then all of the expectation values, probabilities, and etc associated with $\vert\psi\rangle$ are exactly the same as for $\vert\phi\rangle$. For example, the probability for the transition rate between states $\vert\psi\rangle$ and $\vert\xi\rangle$ (I'll assume the latter to be normalized for convenience) will be
\begin{align}
\frac{|\langle\xi|\psi\rangle|^2}{\langle\psi|\psi\rangle} &=
\frac{|\alpha|^2|\langle\xi|\phi\rangle|^2}{|\alpha|^2 \langle\phi|\phi\rangle}, \\
&=
\frac{|\langle\xi|\phi\rangle|^2}{\langle\phi|\phi\rangle}.
\end{align}

An expectation value of some observable $\hat{A}$ also satisfies a similar relation, since

\begin{align}
\frac{\langle\psi|\hat{A}|\psi\rangle}{\langle\psi|\psi\rangle} &=
\frac{|\alpha|^2|\langle\phi|\hat{A}|\phi\rangle}{|\alpha|^2 \langle\phi|\phi\rangle}, \\
&=
\frac{\langle\phi|\hat{A}|\phi\rangle}{\langle\phi|\phi\rangle}.
\end{align}

In short, yes, $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ can be identified with the ray of $|\psi\rangle$. It can represent the pure state because all pure states are defined up to multiplication by a constant complex number.

Notice the necessity of the constancy: phases that depend on space or time do have dynamical effects since they are part of the wavefunction, and can lead, for example, to the [Aharonov–Bohm effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect). Furthermore, relative constants between states can also be relevant ($\vert+\rangle = \frac{
1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\vert 0 \rangle + \vert 1 \rangle\right)$ and $\vert-\rangle = \frac{
1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\vert 0 \rangle - \vert 1 \rangle\right)$ are not the same state, even though the difference appears to be just the phase in front of $\vert 1 \rangle$). Overall phases are irrelevant, but relative phases are relevant.